# Step by step shop in magento?

Tags: magento2

I am wondering whether I should start my store with Magento. The case is that I will want to offer step by step process (around 12 different product categories, from which user will have to pick one of each). This means, that the scenario will be as following: User sees step 1, needs to select 1 product from step 1 products, then goes to step 2, where he needs to select 1 product from step 2 products, etc. On top of that, at the very beginning, he will have to pick city, to determine the prices.

Could magento handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very easily with bundled or grouped products, depending on needs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68377)

Comment: @liyakat the question is clear enough and i had to do a quite similar task. the answer is clear imo. there is nothing wrong with 1 line answers if a 1 line answer answers the question.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga, Answer should be more elaborated and in well manner, you can also add same thing as comment as well

Comment: @liyakat it's not a comment that asks for clarification, it's an answer. You make an assumption that 1 line answers are not answers which I don't think it is right, but feel free to downvote, that's what the system is for.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga,Bro i don't want to down vote your answer,it is really good attempt to solve this problem but aim is to close as SE answer should be in detail.Sorry